# Is the Louvre Pyramid oriented to the four cardinal points of the compass?

Tags: engineering-history, architecture

The four sides of the *Great Pyramid of Giza* are oriented to the four cardinal directions of the compass (north, west, east, south).

**Did I.M. Pei do the same with the *Louvre Pyramid*?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear so:

[image]
(screen shot [from google maps](https://www.google.be/maps/@48.860611,2.337644,745m/data=!3m1!1e3).)

Comment: I presume this screenshot is oriented so _Le Café Marly_ is true north?

Comment: yeah I didn't touch the compass,

Comment: Thank you. At least now I know. (P.S. I guess I.M.Pei's pyramid was constrained by the Louvre Museum at the right. But aren't some buildings (or at least their windows) supposed to be oriented so they face/avoid the sun's rays at appropriate times of the day/season? Oh well, just an afterthought.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII That doesn't mean they have to be exactly aligned to the cardinals. you rarely have a properly aligned plot of land to put your building and cutting off a corner to get aligned will sacrifice floor surface area for marginal benefit.

Comment: @ratchetfreak  The pyramid is aligned with Louvre itself.  If you zoom out the aerial photo a little, you'll see that Louvre is oriented along the river to the south.  The Louvre is oriented neither by true North nor by magnetic North at the time it was built.  Actually, the pyramid itself would have more area if it were aligned with the true North.  That would be extra quirky/whimsical/French, in addition to having the pyramid there in the first place.